# Need help understanding Python syntax to write recursion when solving max binary tree depth

Tags: python

The problem is about solving max depth of a binary tree using recursion. originally from leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/solution/

I'm trying to understand the code by walking through a real example. root = 3, left child = 9, right child = null. should return 2.

Specifically, I don't quite understand how left_height would get int value of 1. I understand that right_height is None, therefore 0.

It would be great someone can walk through the example with the real value. I understand the algorithm well. I'm not very familiar with manipulating of python objects.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """ 
        if root is None: 
            return 0 
        else: 
            left_height = self.maxDepth(root.left) 
            right_height = self.maxDepth(root.right) 
            return max(left_height, right_height) + 1
```

Comment: Did you try printing (root, left_height, right_height) in each recursive call or stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @yassin yes, root, root.left, root.right all return to an address of the object, not the real value though.. i know root.val would return me the real value. but i was still confused how maxDepth would turn magically an object to return an int...

Comment: I don't quite understand how left_height would get int value of 1 , "this just mean that if there exist a left node for a root then add 1 to the height of that tree. for that path"

Comment: Me nether, where did this one come from. Did you include a context, so that we know what you are asking about. And what is root=3, leftchild=9 …?

Comment: sorry my bad! i meant root.left not left_height...

Comment: In an example, if the tree has root = 3, left child =9, right child = null, the result should return 2 because the max depth of the tree is 2.

Comment: I followed the link, these numbers are irrelevant, so `[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`, is the same as `[1,1,1,null,null,1,1]`, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left node has no further left or right, so it'll return `max(0,0)+1`, or 1

This call comes back up the tree to the root to return `max(1,0)+1`, and the final result is 2

Comment: aha! yes this is very clear! i didnt realize max(0,0)+1, so 1

Comment: a follow up question. why the end case of the recursion is written "if root is None:" instead of "if root ==null"? how does the input null get to translate into None? (if you look at the leetcode test case input)

Comment: `null` doesn't exist in Python. And `is None` is how you check for None-ness

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link, these numbers are irrelevant so

```
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7
```

is the same as

```
    .
   / \
  .  .
    / \
   .   .
```